# Maps API v3 : map.setCenter not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a setCenter problem with Maps api V3

First here is my code :

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $product["latitude"] ?>,<?= $product["longitude"] ?>);
    var center = myLatlng;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        center = map.getCenter();
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(center);
    });        
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

And then my problem :

- When I take my window from fullscreen to smaller : it works (event is
  triggered twice, don't know why)
- When I make my window fullscreen again : it doesn't work
- When i make my window smaller or larger : it does nothing as well

The rest of the map works well, I really don't understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

That runs initialize immediately and uses its return value as a function to execute when the window load event runs.

This is also not correct:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    center = map.getCenter();
});
```

`map` is not a DOM element, that should be google.maps.event.addListener.

Your issue is because you are't triggering the `map` resize event when the map's DOM element changes size.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  map.setCenter(center);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74s6ddsk/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413);
  var center = myLatlng;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    center = map.getCenter();
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(center);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Well, I followed your instructions and it works so I have nothing else to say but thanks !

Comment: I forgot `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`. THanks!!